# Serialize and deserialize datetime with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a class which contains the ocject `DateTime`.

```
public class Refuel 
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Litre { get; set; }
}
```

When deserializing my text file I get an error.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OD_TankApp.Models.Refueling]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'DateTime', line 1, position 12.
```

I tried already with Json settings but it didnt helped.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat};
```

this is the json string:

```
"{\"DateTime\":\"2019-02-28T16:21:06.36845+01:00\",\"Litre\":\"23\"}}"
```

Comment: your json is incorrect, you have 2 trailing '}'

Comment: My guess is that you try to deserialize the json string into an array or list of `Refuel`. Try `var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Refuel>(json);`

Comment: I do indeed deserialize it as a list. I need to, because I want a history of `Refuel`. At the moment of deserializing theres just one `Refuel` in the list - is that the problem?

Comment: @svenQ could be, I cut if off for giving you guys an example. but yeah, sorry, i forgot to value this string by a website. the string in my code is correct.

Comment: Your current json string does not define a list. Change it to `"[{\"DateTime\":\"2019-02-28T16:21:06.36845+01:00\",\"Litre\":\"23\"}]"` and it will work

Comment: @paulvoelker the error has nothing to do with dates or settings. You can't deserialize an *object* into an array or vice versa. The error says that you tried to deserialize an object into a List. You can't do that. Deserialize the object and put it in an array if you want. Or find out *why* you got a single object instead of an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize a json string which represents a single object into a list/array of objects which will not work. Either deserialize it into a single object like this:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Refuel>(json);
```

Or change your json string to contain a list of objects:

> "[{\"DateTime\":\"2019-02-28T16:21:06.36845+01:00\",\"Litre\":\"23\"}]"

Now you can deserialize it like that:

```
var objArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Refuel[]>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize an array, you'll need to secify that ([])

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Refuel[]>(json);
```

Comment: The OP already tries to deserialize the json string into an array/list. It's the json which does not match.